# ISO 8601 extended duration format PnYnMnDTnHnMnS in R

Tags: r, datetime, duration, lubridate

Is there any way to parse [ISO 8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) e.g. "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" and return something like:
"3 years, 6 months, 4 days, 12:30:05"

I had no luck with [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html)'s durations or [parsedate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/parsedate/index.html) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also not aware of any such package (may be it exists) to solve but you can use regex to parse it in your way, since the pattern will be fixed ("PnYnMnDTnHnMnS"), according to Wikipedia:

```
gsub("P(\\d+)Y(\\d+)M(\\d+)DT(\\d+)H(\\d+)M(\\d+)S", "\\1 Years, \\2
Months, \\3 Days, \\4:\\5:\\6", "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S")
```

**Output**:

```
[1] "3 Years, 6 Months, 4 Days, 12:30:5"
```

**EDIT**:

In case you are interested in only padding zeroes of seconds not anything else, I have added here two elements in the vector one with single digit of seconds, other with two digits of seconds(Assuming seconds will not go beyond 60) to validate the regex:

```
    vect <- c("P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S", "P3Y6M4DT12H30M15S")
    ifelse(grepl(".*M(\\d)S", vect), gsub("P(\\d+)Y(\\d+)M(\\d+)DT(\\d+)H(\\d+)M(\\d)S", "\\1 Years, \\2 Months, \\3 Days, \\4:\\5:0\\6", vect), gsub("P(\\d+)Y(\\d+)M(\\d+)DT(\\d+)H(\\d+)M(\\d+)S", "\\1 Years, \\2 Months, \\3 Days, \\4:\\5:\\6", vect))
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "3 Years, 6 Months, 4 Days, 12:30:05"  
[2] "3 Years, 6 Months, 4 Days, 12:30:15"
```

In case you are interested in padding every element of single digit number:

```
topad <- gsub("P(\\d+)Y(\\d+)M(\\d+)DT(\\d+)H(\\d+)M(\\d+)S", "\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4-\\5-\\6", vect)
library(stringr)
splitvect <- strsplit(topad,split="-")
unlist(lapply(splitvect, function(x)paste0(str_pad(x, 2, "0", side="left"), c("Years, ", "Months, ", "Days, ", ":", ":", ""), collapse= "")))
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "03Years, 06Months, 04Days, 12:30:05"
[2] "03Years, 06Months, 04Days, 12:30:15"
```

Comment: With this pattern can single numbers have one leading zero e.g. 05 instead of 5, "12:30:05"?